# How can I tell Python to end after pylab.show()?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I generated a plot in Python using Pylab:

```
pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.show()
```

But now the script seems to block when it completes.  When I break it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the script ends, closing the plot windows.  How can I tell Python not to block?

Comment: If you can use IPython in pylab mode (`ipython --pylab`), you shouldn't even need to call `show()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the program to end (without blocking, returning control to the terminal) and yet keep the plot window open?

If so, and if using unix, you could fork a subprocess, and use [os.setsid](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.setsid) to make a new session with the subprocess as session leader:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

pi = np.pi
arctan = np.arctan

if os.fork():
    # Parent
    pass
else:
    # Child
    os.setsid()
    x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
    plt.plot(x,arctan(x))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Are `sys`  and `multiprocessing` imports needed?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `plt.ion()` (turns on the interactive mode)
and later `plt.draw()` if needed.
plt is matplotlib.pyplot (which I think is also visible via pylab.*)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sega_sai's answer. However, (at least what I have seen is that) sometimes after the plot has been displayed, it goes into a "Not Responding" mode and you just have to kill the process anyways. The best option (if you have installed IPython) is to start IPython with the "--pylab" option ("ipython --pylab"). 
[Please note that my experience is on a Windows 7 machine.]